# How to check if a class has overriden a default method from an interface using Reflection in Kotlin or Java?

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection

I have an interface with a default method, and two classes which implement this interface. One of the classes overrides the default method, and the other does not.

```
interface MyType {
  fun giveHello(): String = "Hello!"
}

class Polite: MyType {
  // Does not override giveHello()
}

class Rude: MyType {
  override fun giveHello(): String = "I don't like you"
}
```

I get access to the `giveHello` method using reflection like this:

```
val methodOfPolite = Polite::class.java.getDeclaredMethod("giveHello")
val methodOfRude = Rude::class.java.getDeclaredMethod("giveHello")
```

There's one weird thing here. The polite class does not override the `giveHello` method, but the `declaringClass` of this method object still points to `Polite`.

**So is there a way I can check whether the class actually did override the default interface method or not?**

My use case looks something like this (assuming we can get the behaviour I'm asking for in a property called `isOverriden`):

```
if (methodOfPolite.isOverriden) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As described in [KT-4779](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4779), currently Kotlin default functions are not implemented using actual Java/JVM default methods. The default implementation lives in a static method instead, and all classes using that default implementation just call that static method. This is done to ensure Kotlin default functions also work on the 1.6 JVM target which doesn't have them yet.

So your code roughly compiles to this Java equivalent:

```java
public interface MyType {
  public String giveHello();

  public static class MyTypeImpls {
     public static String giveHello() { return "Hello!" }
  }
}

public final class Polite implements MyType {
  //does not override
  public String giveHello() { return MyType.MyTypeImpls.giveHello() }
}

public final class Rude implements MyType {
  //does override
  override fun giveHello() { return "I don't like you" }
}
```

This is why java reflection thinks both classes override the function, ie because they actually do.

You need to use Kotlin reflection here, notably [`declaredMemberFunctions`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/declared-member-functions.html) and [`memberFunctions`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/member-functions.html):

```kotlin
fun overridesGiveHello<T: MyType>(cls: KClass<T>) =
        cls.memberFunctions.first { it.name == "giveHello" } in cls.declaredFunctions

println(overridesGiveHello(Polite::class)) //false
println(overridesGiveHello(Rude::class))  //true
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works well.

Here's a neat little extension function building on your answer: 
`infix fun KClass<*>.doesOverride(methodName: String): Boolean { return this.memberFunctions.first { it.name == methodName } in this.declaredFunctions }`

Comment: I just tried this but with abstract classes, and it did *not* work. The subclass's `memberFunctions` actually had method instances even for non-overridden methods in the superclass, which is strange. Meanwhile I don't want to check only `declaredMemberFunctions` so I can support class hierarchies. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: @PhilipGuin This still seems to work for me, Kotlin `1.6.20`, jvmTarget `1.8`, although I had to change the `KClass` generic type a bit (I also updated the answer). What versions are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually doing something a bit different. I'm checking if the subclass's method is present in the superclass's declared methods. I was looking for a way to determine if the subclass or any superclass overrides the method, not just the immediate class via `declaredMemberFunctions`. For now I'm just using the JVM reflection methods, which make this a bit easier. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case I think the [`isDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#isDefault--) method should return `true`.

I would have expected `Polite::class.java.getMethod("giveHello")` to return the method, but not `getDeclaredMethod()`, but we are in the world of using Java reflection on Kotlin classes and interfaces. The Java expectations may not be met.

You could use kotlin reflection though, use `declaredMembers` to get the properties and functions from the [`KClass`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/index.html). Note, import from `kotlin.reflect.full` is required, since extension methods are used.

Comment: `isDefault` returns false for "giveHello" method of both classes, whether I use `getDeclaredMethod` or `getMethod`.

[Here's some code](https://pl.kotl.in/Q4yTRgdMH) to prove

Comment: Interesting. The link to the code doesn’t work though.

Comment: The link works fine. I just tested it on multiple browsers and devices.

Comment: Now it works fine. Previously it was the default example.

Comment: Edited my answer to include kotlin reflection. Kotlin playground support is limited though.

Comment: Thanks, the issue seems to be that Kotlin does not really create bytecode with default method interfaces even when targeting 1.8.

I'm still considering whether it's better to write my interface in java for this small task, or to use Kotlin reflect.